# Highcharts, add icon to plotline?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, icons

I have a Highchart chart where display some data and a line that indicates some limit. If the data is over the limit, I set an alert.

I try to visualize this limit using a plotline. This works great, but I woudl like to add an arrow / triangle icon so the user can see if the alert triggers if the value is above, or below the threshold.

See for a similar chart: http://jsfiddle.net/os5gjch5/2/, relevant code:

```
   plotLines: [{
         value: 150,
                    color: 'red',
                    width: 1,
                    zIndex:100
        }],
```

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

I could not find an easy option for this the the documentation... Any hints?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of what you've done?

Comment: Maybe this can be of help: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/

Comment: @Dmitry added a fiddle;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `label` to your plot line

```js
label: {
  text: " Warning",
  style: {
    "color": "red"
  }
}
```

[Here](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/) are some more Unicode arrows you can choose from. [Docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines.label) for other label properties. 
 You can remove the word "Warning" and play with the `y` property of the label if you want the arrow to sit exactly on the plot line.

**Working example:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
           value: 150,
           color: 'red',
           width: 1,
           zIndex:100,
              label: {
                  text: " Warning",
                  style: { 
                      "color": "red"
                  }
              }
        }],
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Any chance the label can be aligned totally left?

Comment: Look in the docs I linked. `align: "left"` is the default. You can also play with `x` and `y` to position it the way you want.